# JQuery-like programming shortcut for classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, shortcut

I am writing some javascript and HTML, and because of the nature of what I am writing, I was inspired to write some shortcut functions. I commonly use

```
document.getElementById()
```

and

```
document.getElementsbyClassName()
```

I often access the style attributes via these methods, so I wrote this shortcut function in a JQuery-like style:

```
var $=function(elemId){
    return(document.getElementById(elemId).style);
}
```

Say that i have a div with the id 'foo', and want to change the color to red:

```
$('foo').color='red';
```

this saves me a considerable amount of code

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.color='red';
```

especially when I am using this fifty+ times in a script.

I have done something similar with classes, but I cannot access the .style object of the HTML object because of the nature of

```
document.getElementsByClassName()
```

because it returns a string. What I normally have to do is collect the items as an array and iterate through it like so:

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName('class');
for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
x[i].style.color='red';
}
```

As you can see, it takes three times as much code to achieve the same effect with a class as an ID. So what I am asking is this:

Is there a way that I can write a function similar to the one at the top, but works for classes, so that I DO NOT have to iterate through it? The ideal result would be

```
var css=function(classname){
//code here
}
css('class').color='red';
```

So basically what I want is a function that can do what my ID function does but with a class, and without having to iterate through the class.

## Disclaimer

What I DO NOT WANT is an answer that involves JQuery. I am unable to use it, which is why I am writing the code this way by myself. Regular JavaScript answers only, please.

If you have any questions, post a comment and I'll try and clarify. Thanks!

Comment: jQuery uses `.css('key','value')` for a reason...

Comment: Just for reference you can look into this: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/ where John goes through a simple method to create instance of function similar to jQuery - then you can add the answer function you get to a prototype of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
var css = function(classname, style) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    for(var s in style) {
      if(style.hasOwnProperty(s)) {
        x[i].style[s] = style[s];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
css('class', { color: 'red' });
```

Of course, the properties should match dom style properties ('backgroundColor' and not 'background-color').

Comment: Thanks! This is super close to what I'm looking for, and this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the way you formulated it.  The problem is that the array can't be notified of a change when you use the "=".  Even jQuery doesn't do it this way.

You can do something like:

```
css('class').set('color', 'red');
```

Your function would then just have to iterate over the array and set each element's property.

Comment: Thanks for the  help. Appreciate it. I'll wait and see if any more helpful answers come in, though. I'm sure there is. It's programming. There is ALWAYS a way.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to avoid the for loop.

Comment: Not helpful. There clearly IS a way, as an above answer suggests. I have tested it and it works. Looks like you didn't do your research.

Comment: @Leshy there is always an iteration involved. Bill is wright with that "at least one iteration" context. Even with @manji's answer you could see, there is always a loop running over the collected elements fetched using, `document.getElementsByClassName(classname);`

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary yes, but I was referring to an iteration OUTSIDE of the function. I'm sorry I was unclear.

Comment: Hey @Leshy , that's cool you needn be.. I got what you were trying to ask but generally this happens with relatively longer questions(as in text size wise) that often we misunderstand/override what the author actually wanted to ask, as some of us get lost in the other small problems which lye within the bigger prob.. :)